# Encrypt or Protect asp application code

Tags: security, encryption, asp-classic

My classic asp application would run on local system of users via internet browser. The code file resides in the root folder of the `C:` drive. But I want that the code cannot be seen by the users, and even if the file is opened then the code is not readable easily, like encrypted or encoded. I want to protect the code from being copied. Is it possible? If so, then how?

Comment: ASP is server side code, which means it is interpreted by a webserver, you can.r just open an asp file directly in a web browser and expect to display correctly.  If you are saying you are on a network and want to run your pages on an intranet then you can create a directory to which only your account and the IUSR account (which the webserver uses to read/write/execute files) has been granted access.  Anyway, encrypted classic asp files are very easy to decrypt, as I discovered when I inherited a project and had to do this

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to Host application on one System and if other system is in connected in LAN they can use same site via hosted URL.

To deploy code in each system is not a good practice to secure.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with everybody else, suggesting a different design, but I will give you an answer that I think is applicable if you're dead set on what you're doing:

Write your server-side logic in Visual Basic 6 or .NET and expose as COM objects.

(A wilder idea would be to implement your own ISAPI filter, but I am not positive if the APIs allow you to intercept the loading of the source... thinking and googling around make me think that that's not possible, but not 100% sure)

I have done this with COM objects.